# How to call startActivityOnResult without extending Activity on a Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a custom keyboard with the service:

```
public class testBoard extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
```

and inside, I'm trying to start an intent using startActivity(activity) and I'm trying to wait for the activity to call finish() and then do something. I cannot use startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult because testBoard does not extend Activity(I think). How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult()` is only available from real on-screen activities. Please redesign your application so that the user interface is driven from activities, then have your service scan for devices.

Comment: I'm trying to make a button show a list of options the users could choose from. I'm using an activity to have a screen with a ListView. Is there a better alternative to this?